# Php unlimited category find all parent id by one id

Tags: php

my category table is like this

```
ID - parent_id - name
1    null        technology
2    1           mobile phone
3    1           desktop computer
4    2           apple
5    4           ios 11
```

this hierarchy is Technology > mobile phone > apple > ios 11. okay, I don't have any problem so far but;

I have category id 5 "ios 11", and I want to find all parent_id with array. My code is like this;

```
$id = $_POST['katID']; // "5" ios 11
    
    
function buildTree($pdo,$id) {
    $elementsq = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id,parent_id FROM categories WHERE id = ?");
    $elementsq->execute(array($id));
    $elements = $elementsq->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $elementsq = null;
        
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['id'] == $id) {
            array_push($branch,$element['id']);
            buildTree($pdo, $element['parent_id']);
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
    

$arr = buildTree($pdo,$id);
    
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

I want an output like this;

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1, // technology
    [1] => 2, // mobile phone
    [3] => 4, // Apple
    [4] => 5 // ios 11
)
```

Thank you for your help. Yours truly

Comment: So WHY have you tagged `javascript` and `jquery` when the question only refers to PHP. I removed the spam tags

Comment: I'm a little out of mind as I've been dealing with this problem for two days. Sorry

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have written?

Comment: _Small Point_ fetchAll is not needed or a foreach loop when Only ONE row will be returned by the query

Comment: If you want to call this function recursively, then remove `$branch = array();` from the middle of it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't fetch records one by one. If data is not huge then fetch them directly and then process it in php itself.

```
// Data fetched from database.
$arr = [
    [ 'ID' => 1, 'parent_id' => null, 'name'=> 'technology'],
    [ 'ID' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name'=> 'mobile phone'],
    [ 'ID' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name'=> 'desktop computer'],
    [ 'ID' => 4, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name'=> 'apple'],
    [ 'ID' => 5, 'parent_id' => 4, 'name'=> 'ios 11']
];

// Create a child => parent hash to quickly search in further processing.
$arrTemp = [];

foreach($arr as $data){
    $arrTemp[$data['ID']] = $data['parent_id'];
}

// Node for which parents to be find.
$current = 5;
$arrResult = [];
do {
    $arrResult[]    =   $current;
    $current = $arrTemp[$current];
} while ($current !== null);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($arrResult);
Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
)
```